# how to connect web app packages?

Tags: database

```
public boolean createNewAccount(CustomerDTO customerDTO, AccountDTO accountDTO, Connection connection) throws NamingException, SQLException {
        CustomerDAO customerDAO=dAOFactory.createCustomerDAO();
        AcountDAO acountDAO=dAOFactory.createAcountDAO();

        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        try{

        boolean createNewAccount = customerDAO.createNewAccount(customerDTO);

        if (createNewAccount) {

            boolean createNewaccount = acountDAO.createNewaccount(accountDTO);

                if (createNewaccount) {

                    connection.commit();
                    return true;


                }else{
                    connection.rollback();
                    return false;
                }

        }else{
            connection.rollback();
            return false;
        }
        }finally{
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);
            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  PLease take some time to read [ask].  What is the **exact** problem you are encountering?

Answer (score 0):

create database abcbank;
use abcbank;

create table customer(
    nic VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    firstnmae VARCHAR(100),
    lastname VARCHAR(100),
    address VARCHAR(100),
    contact int(10),
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(nic)
);

create table account(
  accNo VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
  nic VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
  balance float (10),
  CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(accNo,nic),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(nic) REFERENCES customer(nic)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

create table transation(
    transNo VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    accNo   VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    nic  VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    amount FLOAT(10)NOT NULL,
    transactiontype VARCHAR(100),
    date date,
    time time,
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY(transNo,accNo,nic),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(accNo) REFERENCES account(accNo)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(nic) REFERENCES account(nic)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

```
        <Resource auth="Container" 
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
          maxActive="50" 
          maxAge="10000" 
          maxIdle="10" 
          maxWait="100000" 
          name="jdbc/thogakade" 
          password="deshan" 
          testOnBorrow="true" 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/thogakade?autoReconnect=true" 
          username="root" validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>
```

resouse abstrct class

protected  abstract DataSource createDataSource()throws NamingException;

```
public  DataSource getDataSource()throws NamingException{
    DataSource dataSource=createDataSource();
    return dataSource;
}

impl    
@Override
protected DataSource createDataSource() throws NamingException {
    InitialContext context=new InitialContext();
    DataSource dataSource=(DataSource) context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/thogakade");
    return  dataSource;
}

dao impl

 public boolean createNewAccount(CustomerDTO dTO) throws NamingException, SQLException {
    String sql="INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement stm=dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
    stm.setString(1, dTO.getNic());
    stm.setString(2, dTO.getFirstName());
    stm.setString(3, dTO.getLastName());
    stm.setString(4, dTO.getAddress());
    stm.setInt(5, dTO.getTpno());
    int res=stm.executeUpdate();
    return (res>0);
}

@Override
public CustomerDTO serchCustomerByNIC(String nic) throws NamingException, SQLException {
   String sql="SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE nic='"+nic+"'";
   CustomerDTO customerDTO=null;
    Statement s=dataSource.getConnection().createStatement();
    ResultSet rst=s.executeQuery(sql);
    if (rst.next()) {
        customerDTO=new CustomerDTO(rst.getString(1),rst.getString(2),rst.getString(3),rst.getString(4),rst.getInt(5));
    }
    return customerDTO;
}

 public ArrayList<TransationDTO> getAllTransation() throws NamingException, SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * from transation";
    Statement statement = dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rst = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    ArrayList<TransationDTO> lsit = new ArrayList<>();
    while (rst.next()) {
        if (lsit == null) {
            lsit = new ArrayList<>();
        }else{
            TransationDTO dTO=new TransationDTO(rst.getString(1),rst.getString(2),rst.getString(3),rst.getFloat(4),rst.getString(5),rst.getString(6),rst.getString(6));
            lsit.add(dTO);
        }

    }
    return lsit;
}
  @Override
public boolean updateAccount(AccountDTO accountDTO) throws NamingException, SQLException {
   String sql="UPDATE account SET balance=?,nic=? WHERE accNo=?";
   PreparedStatement stm = dataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
    stm.setString(1, accountDTO.getAccountNo());
    stm.setString(2, accountDTO.getNic());
    stm.setFloat(3, accountDTO.getBalance());
    int res = stm.executeUpdate();
    return (res > 0);
}

daofacimpl
private Resource resource;

public DAOFactoryImpl(Resource resource) {
    this.resource = resource;
}

@Override
public CustomerDAO createCustomerDAO() throws NamingException, SQLException {
    DataSource dataSource=resource.getDataSource();
    CustomerDAO customerDAO=new CustomerDaoImpl(dataSource);
    return customerDAO;
}
```

service leyer
//

service impl
private DAOFactory dAOFactory;

```
public CustomerServiveImpl(DAOFactory dAOFactory) {
    this.dAOFactory = dAOFactory;
}



@Override
public CustomerDTO serchCustomerByNIC(String nic) throws NamingException, SQLException {
    CustomerDAO customerDAO=dAOFactory.createCustomerDAO();
    return customerDAO.serchCustomerByNIC(nic);
}

@Override
public boolean createNewAccount(CustomerDTO customerDTO, AccountDTO accountDTO, Connection connection) throws NamingException, SQLException {
    CustomerDAO customerDAO=dAOFactory.createCustomerDAO();
    AcountDAO acountDAO=dAOFactory.createAcountDAO();

    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    try{

    boolean createNewAccount = customerDAO.createNewAccount(customerDTO);

    if (createNewAccount) {

        boolean createNewaccount = acountDAO.createNewaccount(accountDTO);

            if (createNewaccount) {

                connection.commit();
                return true;


            }else{
                connection.rollback();
                return false;
            }

    }else{
        connection.rollback();
        return false;
    }
    }finally{
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        return true;
    }


}

service facimpl

private DAOFactory dAOFactory;

public ServiceFactoryImpl(DAOFactory dAOFactory) {
    this.dAOFactory = dAOFactory;
}

@Override
public CustomerService createCustomerService() throws NamingException, SQLException {
    CustomerService customerService=new CustomerServiveImpl(dAOFactory);
    return customerService;
}

web..serv

Resource resource = new ResourceImpl();
DAOFactory dAOFactory = new DAOFactoryImpl(resource);
ServiceFactory serviceFactory = new ServiceFactoryImpl(dAOFactory);

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    try {
        String accno=request.getParameter("accno");
        AcountService acountService=serviceFactory.createAcountService();
        CustomerAccDetailDTO customeraccde = acountService.searchByAccNo(accno);

        Gson gson=new GsonBuilder().create();
        String list = gson.toJson(customeraccde);
        writer.write(list);


    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        ServletException exception=new ServletException(ex);
        Logger.getLogger(SercletDepositeCustomerSearch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ServletException exception=new ServletException(ex);
        Logger.getLogger(SercletDepositeCustomerSearch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ServletException exception=new ServletException(ex);
        Logger.getLogger(SercletDepositeCustomerSearch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
        if (writer!=null) {
            writer.close();
        }





          ajx
```

$("#serchc").click(function (){
    var qs="?accno="+$("#accno").val();

```
$.getJSON("SercletDepositeCustomerSearch"+qs,function(respoce){
    alert(qs);
   $("#fname").val(respoce.firstName) ;
   $("#sname").val(respoce.lastName);
   $("#nic").val(respoce.nic);
   $("#add").val(respoce.address)
   $("#balance").val(respoce.balance);
   $("#tp").val(respoce.contact)
});
```

});